# Como adicionar subitens de uma ListView em um Memo?

Tags: delphi

Tenho um ListView com 5 campos. Preciso pegar o campo de número 5 da ListView e adicioná-lo em um Memo.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(LV1.Selected.SubItems[5]);
```

Infelizmente não deu certo. Ele não dá erro algum mas também não faz nada. O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegue a lista de todos os itens do seu ListView, depois pegue o quinto item da lista, e por fim pegue o seu texto. Exemplo:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(LV1.Items.Item[4].Caption); //se quiser pegar o quinto ponha índice 4
```

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado amigo!